# RSS feed URL is broken when i click on RSS

Tags: rss, liferay

I have a field for RSS when i click on it it found the URL link is broken and missing p_l_id.

> http://www.xyz.com/c/message_boards/find_message?p_l_id=&messageId=24867

p_1_id is missing inside link.

Comment: Please add some more details to your question. Where is the RSS link?

Comment: i have the custom forum portlet, after adding a thread inside forum when we click on RSS option of the thread we redirected to a xml file where the link seems broken. as we add a forum GBTU inside forum! and when we click on RSS we reidrected to the link 
http://localhost:8080/c/message_boards/find_message?**p_l_id=&**messageId=24867

Comment: But we should redirect to  localhost:8080/c/message_boards/find_message?p_l_id=p_l_id&messageId=24867

Comment: where p_|_id is missing after =&message

Comment: Please help, i am stuck on it